# having problems with $_get

Tags: php

I have a gallery an trying to change the first picture in every  page but it only displays one the same picture in every page to see what imean see [here](http://mentalblur.com/desert-escape-pc-game-steam-1.html)

```
                <?php
                if ($GET["id"])
                    $imageInfo = $indexClass->getGalleryImageById($GET["id"]);
                else
                    $imageInfo = $indexClass->getLastGalleryImage();

                ?>
                <img id="imgContent" src="public/gallery/<?php echo $imageInfo; ?>" width="600" height="415"
                     class="img-border"/>

                <a id="imgContentLink" href="public/gallery/<?php echo $imageInfo; ?>" class="fancybox-thumb"
                   rel="fancybox-thumb"><img class="zoom" src="css/images/zoom.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Is that the superglobal you are trying to use? that is $_GET, check the docs... http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: i see `$GET[]` instead of `$_GET[`, notice the `_`. The second one allows you to access the GET params.

Comment: You wrote $_GET twice (title, code) and both wrong: you should be more careful

Comment: And in your title you say `$_get`, in lowercase instead of uppercase. You can't be sloppy like this if you expect to have a career as a programmer -- computers are very exacting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code and modify `$GET` into `$_GET`, like follows

```
if ($_GET["id"]) {
  $imageInfo = $indexClass->getGalleryImageById($_GET["id"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you use `$GET` instead of `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
            if ($_GET["id"])
                $imageInfo = $indexClass->getGalleryImageById($_GET["id"]);
            else
                $imageInfo = $indexClass->getLastGalleryImage();

            ?>
            <img id="imgContent" src="public/gallery/<?php echo $imageInfo; ?>" width="600" height="415"
                 class="img-border"/>

            <a id="imgContentLink" href="public/gallery/<?php echo $imageInfo; ?>" class="fancybox-thumb"
               rel="fancybox-thumb"><img class="zoom" src="css/images/zoom.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Copy this code and replace with your old code.

Comment: You can edit your answer instead of expanding it in comments.

Comment: ok you are right. next time will do like that.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump your your $_GET to see what is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

change your code from

`$GET`

to

`$_GET`